# How to apply a styles based on book ID or card ID when click function happens on particular card in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I developed one page which is responsible for Displaying Books and the response is coming from backend API based on the response data it displays as like a cards.

Each Book card contains Two button sections in first section it contains ADD TO BAG and WISHLIST buttons (by default it should be visible),in second section it contains one button called ADDED TO BAG(by default it should be hidden).

if the  user clicks on any card "ADD TO BAG" button then it should be hidden (ADD TO BAG && WISHLIST)and displays the ADDED TO BAG button  of a particular clicked card only .please help me to restrict the styles for remaining cards(except clicked card).

This is default page before clicking on ADD TO BAG button
[image: Before click]

This is How i am getting my output after i click on any card ADD TO BAG button but i need to apply the styles on particular clicked card only
[image: After Click]

`DisplayBooks.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="carddisplay-section">
      <div v-for="book in books" :key="book.id" class="card book">
          <div class="image-section">
              <div class="image-container">
                  <img  v-bind:src="book.file" />
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-section">
              {{book.name}}
          </div>
          <div class="author-section">
              by {{book.author}}
          </div>
          <div class="price-section">
              Rs. {{book.price}}<label class="default">(2000)</label>
              <button v-if="flag" class="btn-grp" type="submit" @click="handlesubmit();Togglebtn();">close</button>
          </div>
          <div class="buttons">
  <!-- This is my button section -->            
  <div class="button-groups">
                  
                  <button type="button"  @click="toggle(book.id);toggleClass(book.id);" v-bind:class="[storeBooks.indexOf(book.id) >-1 ? 'red' : 'blue']" class="AddBag">Add to Bag</button>
                  
                  <button  class="wishlist">wishlist</button>
              </div>
              <!-- v-if="state==false" -->
              <div v-bind:class="[!(storeBooks.indexOf(book.id)) >-1 ? 'blue':'red']" @click="toggle(book.id)" class="AddedBag">
                  <button class="big-btn">Added to Bag</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  <!-- <Cart :cardId="clickedCard" v-if="false" /> -->
  </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  import service from '../service/User'
  export default {
      data() {
          return {
              isActive:true,
              storeBooks:[],
              result: 0,
              authorPrefix: 'by',
              pricePrefix: 'Rs.',
              defaultStrikePrice: '(2000)',
              buttonValue: 'close',
              flag: true,
              state: true,
              clickedCard: '',
              books: [{
                  id: 0,
                  file: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41MdP5Tn0wL._SX258_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg',
                  name: 'Dont Make me think',
                  author: 'Sai',
                  price: '1500'
              }, ]
          }
      },
      methods: {
          toggleClass: function(event){
              this.isActive = !this.isActive;
              return event;
          },
          toggle (id) {
            this.clickedCard = id;
            const index = this.storeBooks.indexOf(id);
            if(index > -1) {this.storeBooks = this.storeBooks.splice(index,1)}
            else{
              this.storeBooks.add(id)
            }},
          flip() {
              this.state = !this.state;
          },
          Togglebtn() {
              this.flag = !this.flag;
          },
          handlesubmit() {
              service.userDisplayBooks().then(response => {
                  this.books.push(...response.data);     
              })
          },
      }
  }
  </script>
  
  <style lang="scss" scoped>
      @import "@/styles/DisplayBooks.scss";
  </style>
```

After changing the component code how  i am getting output
[image: Now i am getting]
but actually how i am expecting is [[what i need is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjYMB.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjYMB.png)

`DisplayBooks.scss`

```
@import "colors";
.carddisplay-section {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: space-around;
    gap: 10px;
}
.card:hover{
    box-shadow:0.6px 0.6px 0.6px 0.6px rgb(173, 206, 206);
}
.card {
    margin-top: 55px;
    margin-left: 110px;
    background:$pink;
    // width: 235px;
    // height: 275px;
    width: 235px;
height: 315px;
    background: $pale_white 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border: 1px solid $border_clr;
    border-radius: 3px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.image-section {
    width: 233px;
    height: 172px;
    background: #F5F5F5 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
    opacity: 1;
}

img{
    margin-left: 67px;
    margin-top: 17px;
    width: 105px;
    height: 135px;
    opacity: 1;
    border:none;
}

.title-section {
    text-align: left;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/19px Roboto;
    letter-spacing: 0.2px;
    color: $light_black;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    width: 130px;
    height: 19px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.author-section {
    text-align: left;
    font: normal normal normal 13px/13px Roboto;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: $light_grey;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 123px;
    height: 13px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 7px;
}

.price-section {
    text-align: left;
    font: normal normal bold 12px/16px Roboto;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: $light_black;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 20px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-top: 26px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;

}

label {
    text-decoration-line: line-through;
    font: normal normal normal 10px/13px Roboto;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: $light_grey;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 36px;
    height: 13px;
    margin-top: 2.5px;
    margin-left: 1em;
}

button[type="submit"] {
    border: none;
    padding-left: 65px;
    background: none;
    font-size: 15;
}
.button-groups{
    display:flex;
    margin-top:8px;
}
.AddBag{
    background: #A03037 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border-radius: 2px;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 93px;
    height: 29px;
    margin-left:20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: small;
}
.wishlist{
    margin-left:4px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: small;
    border: 1px solid #7c7a7a;
    border-radius: 2px;
    opacity: 1;
    color: #0A0102;
    width:93px;
}
.big-btn{
    width: 191px;
height: 29px;
margin-left:20px;
background: #3371B5 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
border-radius: 2px;
opacity: 1;
color:#FFFFFF;
}
.red{
    background: red;
   
}   
.blue{
    background: yellow;
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: The above explaination is not clear, please edit it in such a way that we could understand it better

Comment: @Amaarrockz Thanks for replying me , i changed my explanation please look at once

Answer (score 0):

You currently have only one boolean for checking if a book is added to cart or not, and if you add any of them, you trigger the class automatically and it will affect all other books.

You can solve this issue simply by either adding extra key to your books data so that you can check if that individual book is added or not like this using spread operator and map function that comes with arrays:

```
data  = data.map(item => ({...item, isActive: false}))
```

All this code does is takes each one of your book objects and adds isActive key with false value with it. And you can simply use this key in HTML with v-show to show which buttons you like like this:

```
<div class="button-groups" v-show="!book.isActive">
  <button type="button" @click="book.isActive=!book.isActive;" class="AddBag red">Add to Bag</button>
  <button  class="wishlist">wishlist</button>
</div>

<div @click="book.isActive=!book.isActive" class="AddedBag blue" v-show="book.isActive">
  <button class="big-btn">Added to Bag</button>
</div>
```

This way you can control which button you want to show and I recommend you to change isActive variable's name since it's confusing to understand what is active.

Comment: where i have to add the map function after push method na ..?

Comment: You can directly add after you get the result from API. It will work as long as you apply this step before using the array

Comment: it shows syntax error in the spreaded syntax area

Comment: would you try this instead: 

data  = data.map(item => ({...item, isActive: false}))

Comment: it shows no error now but not getting required output, when ever i click on the any card ADD TO BAG button it's hiding and ADDED TO BAG button also hiding and mainly it's applying on all cards and it shows data is not defined

Comment: can you try edited answer, the problem is resulting from we were still changing global isActive variable.

Comment: yeah i tried with your updated answer but getting following errors  78:18  error  'data' is not defined  no-undef
  78:26  error  'data' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: data was for placeholder purposes since yo didn't specify how your API code was. instead of data you should use the variable that you store array that come from API.

Comment: can i pass like this data = data.map(item => ({...item, isActive: false}))

Comment: to give an example how you should use it:
`function async getAPI() {
  const { data } = await axios.get('/apiurl');
  data = data.map(item => ({...item, isActive: false}));
  return data;
}`
and of course this is just an example you need to adapt this code to your codebase.

Comment: inorder to write axios part in same component  i create service directory it's containing axios.js and user.js file

Comment: I cannot give advice on where you should put this code since I have no idea about your codebase. All I am saying is in a place where you get your data from api, or when you register that data to your component, before using it on template, you should apply this code to it.  For example you have `books` in your data so you should manipulate books with this method and send it to template

Answer (score 0):

you can define an array to store which card is added in your component data function，like storeBooks,
in `storeBooks=[]`

```
toggle = (id) => {
 const index = this.storeBooks.indexOf(id);
 if(index > -1) {this.storeBooks = this.storeBooks.splice(index,1)}
 else{
  this.storeBooks.add(id)
 }}
```

in book card, you can
`isActive = storeBooks.indexOf(book.id) > -1`
to set class

like this

```
<template>
  <div class="carddisplay-section">
      <div v-for="book in books" :key="book.id" class="card book">
          <div class="image-section">
              <div class="image-container">
                  <img  v-bind:src="book.file" />
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="title-section">
              {{book.name}}
          </div>
          <div class="author-section">
              by {{book.author}}
          </div>
          <div class="price-section">
              Rs. {{book.price}}<label class="default">(2000)</label>
              <button v-if="flag" class="btn-grp" type="submit" @click="handlesubmit();Togglebtn();">close</button>
          </div>
          <div class="buttons">
  <!-- This is my button section -->            
  <div class="button-groups">
                  
                  <button type="button"  @click="toggle(book.id);toggleClass(book.id);" v-bind:class="[storeBooks.indexOf(book.id) >-1 ? 'red' : 'blue']" class="AddBag">Add to Bag</button>
                  
                  <button  class="wishlist">wishlist</button>
              </div>
              <!-- v-if="state==false" -->
              <div v-bind:class="[storeBooks.indexOf(book.id) >-1 ? 'blue':'red']" @click="toggle(book.id)" class="AddedBag">
                  <button class="big-btn">Added to Bag</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  <!-- <Cart :cardId="clickedCard" v-if="false" /> -->
  </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  import service from '../service/User'
  export default {
      data() {
          return {
              isActive:true,
              storeBooks:[],
              result: 0,
              authorPrefix: 'by',
              pricePrefix: 'Rs.',
              defaultStrikePrice: '(2000)',
              buttonValue: 'close',
              flag: true,
              state: true,
              clickedCard: '',
              books: [{
                  id: 0,
                  file: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41MdP5Tn0wL._SX258_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg',
                  name: 'Dont Make me think',
                  author: 'Sai',
                  price: '1500'
              }, ]
          }
      },
      methods: {
          toggleClass: function(event){
              this.isActive = !this.isActive;
              return event;
          },
          toggle (id) {
            this.clickedCard = id;
            const index = this.storeBooks.indexOf(id);
            if(index > -1) {this.storeBooks = this.storeBooks.splice(index,1)}
            else{
              this.storeBooks.add(id)
            }},
          flip() {
              this.state = !this.state;
          },
          Togglebtn() {
              this.flag = !this.flag;
          },
          handlesubmit() {
              service.userDisplayBooks().then(response => {
                  this.books.push(...response.data);     
              })
          },
      }
  }
  </script>
  
  <style lang="scss" scoped>
      @import "@/styles/DisplayBooks.scss";
  </style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but little bit confusing where to add this answer

Comment: ,maybe you understood a question wrong , what i need is onclick of any card ADD TO BAG button then ADD TO BAG and WISHLIST should be hidden and displays the ADDED TO BAG button on clicked only

Comment: hide or show element , you can use `storeBooks.indexOf(book.id) >-1` to control.

Comment: i simply copy paste your answer , in my UI page i am getting with out ADD TO BAG button and ADDED TO BAG button is visible by default

Comment: in your code, `storeBooks.indexOf(book.id) >-1 ` means show ADDED TO BAG，which would hide ADD TO BAG, use `!(storeBooks.indexOf(book.id) >-1)` to show ADD TO BAG

Comment: when i added !(storeBooks.indexOf(book.id) >-1) this it displays only wishlist button , what i need is onclick of ADD TO BAG button it should hide WISHLIST and ADD To BAG buttons and then it should display ADDED TO BAG button

Comment: i updated in my question section please  look at once

Comment: you shoud add `v-show="storeBooks.indexOf(book.id) >-1"` in ADDED TO BAG container，add `v-show="!(storeBooks.indexOf(book.id) >-1)"`  in you ADD TO BAG  and wishlist container, or use v-if/v-else, to control then.

Comment: i updated my question and how i am getting output image also added and  what's my requirement also added

Comment: why you not add v-show or v-if/else in your code?  I think you dont need to control element show /hide by css in your code,

`<div class="button-groups" v-if="!(storeBooks.indexOf(book.id) >-1)">add to bag xxx</div>
 <div v-else v-bind:class="[storeBooks.indexOf(book.id) >-1 ? 'blue':'red']" @click="toggle(book.id)" class="AddedBag">
                  <button class="big-btn">Added to Bag</button>
              </div>
`

Comment: i added  i think i missed to update my question ,still getting same output it's not working

Comment: delete `storeBooks.indexOf(book.id) >-1` in your button, and add pic after add to bag in desc